# Strange behaviour of unification pattern matching

Tags: prolog, pattern-matching, unification

So here it is, for my sudoku project I have a list, such as :

```
L = [_G1-0:0:0,_G19-0:6:2,_G22-0:7:2,_G25-0:8:2].
```

and I want to filter this to get only the free variables :

```
[_G1, _G19, _G22 and _G25].
```

So wanting that, I wrote this predicate :

```
remove_position([], []) :- !.
remove_position([X-_|Xs], [X|Rs]) :- remove_position(Xs, Rs).
```

When calling

```
?- remove_position(L, Result).
```

SWI-Prolog answers

```
false.
```

So I edited the predicate a little :

```
remove_position([], []) :- !.
remove_position([X-_:_:_|Xs], [X|Rs]) :- remove_position(Xs, Rs).
```

and now it works as expected :

```
?- remove_position(L, Result).
Result = [_G1, _G19, _G22, _G25].
```

Still, I can't see what's wrong with the first one, for me, SWI-Prolog should match 0:0:0 with _ just as well as with _:_:_. Is there something I do not get ? Or is it a SWI-Prolog bug ?

Thanks for any enlightenment !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a term `_G1-2:3:4` without any parentheses, you have to consider the associativity and precedence of the operators in order to find out how the term is parsed.

The term `_G1-2:3:4` is the same as `(_G1-2):(3:4)`, not `_G1-(2:3:4)`, and so the unification of `_G1-2:3:4` and `X-_` fails.

If you add parentheses to your terms, like `_G1-(2:3:4)`, then your original `remove_position/2` predicate will work.